# fig.align in Knitr does not work on GitHub flavoured markdown

Tags: r, github, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to use the fig-align:center option of knitr to center images in my r markdown document.

On the header of my document I have included this line:

```
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.align="center")
```

It seems to be working properly at least partially because in the knit preview, the images are centered like below:

[image: capture1]

However, when I knit the document using the

```
output: github_document
```

option and upload the knitted .md file to my GitHub, the images are no longer centered; it seems like the opts_chunk setting above is no longer functioning.

[image: capture2]

How do I make sure that the fig.align option is equally applied to the .md file that I upload to my GitHub?

Comment: If you really care about this level of details, you should not use Github Flavored Markdown or let Github render Markdown to HTML. You should render Markdown to HTML through Pandoc by yourself. Typically Markdown is supposed to be simple, simple, and simple (no figure alignment support), except when you are using Pandoc's Markdown.

Comment: @Yihui Thank you for the reply! I am a beginner in this field so I am just not yet so fluent in utilizing these tools. I will definitely go ahead and learn more about Markdown.

Comment: No problem. I can certainly understand your confusion.